# Check if a command is in PATH/executable as process

Tags: rust

I want to execute an external program via `std::process::Command::spawn`. Furthermore I want to know the reason why spawning the process failed: is it because the given program name doesn't exist/is not in PATH or because of some different error?

Example code of what I want to achieve:

```
match Command::new("rustc").spawn() {
    Ok(_) => println!("Was spawned :)"),
    Err(e) => {
        if /* ??? */ {
            println!("`rustc` was not found! Check your PATH!")
        } else {
            println!("Some strange error occurred :(");
        }
    }, 
}
```

When I try to execute a program that isn't on my system, I get:

```
Error { repr: Os { code: 2, message: "No such file or directory" } }
```

But I don't want to rely on that. Is there a way to determine if a program exists in PATH?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `e.kind()` to find what [`ErrorKind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/enum.ErrorKind.html) the error was.

```
match Command::new("rustc").spawn() {
    Ok(_) => println!("Was spawned :)"),
    Err(e) => {
        if let NotFound = e.kind() {
            println!("`rustc` was not found! Check your PATH!")
        } else {
            println!("Some strange error occurred :(");
        }
    }, 
}
```

**Edit:** I didn't find any explicit documentation about what error kinds can be returned, so I looked up the source code. It seems the error is returned straight from the OS. The relevant code seems to be in `src/libstd/sys/[unix/windows/..]/process.rs`. A snippet from the Unix version:

**One more edit: On a second thought, I'm not sure if the licenses actually allows posting parts of Rust sources here, so you can see it on [github](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/sys/unix/process.rs#L174)**

Which just returns `Error::from_raw_os_err(...)`. The Windows version seemed more complicated, and I couldn't immediately find where it even returns errors from. Either way, it seems you're at the mercy of your operating system regarding that. At least I found the following test in `src/libstd/process.rs`:

**Same as above: [github](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/process.rs#L751)**

That seems to guarantee that an `ErrorKind::NotFound` should be returned at least when the binary is not found. It makes sense to assume that the OS wouldn't give a NotFound error in other cases, but who knows. If you want to be absolutely sure that the program really was not found, you'll have to search the directories in $PATH manually. Something like:

```
use std::env;
use std::fs;

fn is_program_in_path(program: &str) -> bool {
    if let Ok(path) = env::var("PATH") {
        for p in path.split(":") {
            let p_str = format!("{}/{}", p, program);
            if fs::metadata(p_str).is_ok() {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    false
}

fn main() {
    let program = "rustca"; // shouldn't be found
    if is_program_in_path(program) {
        println!("Yes.");
    } else {
        println!("No.");
    }
}
```

Comment: The PATH separator is `;` on Windows!

Comment: @FrancisGagné and the directory separator `\`. My example was indeed Unix only. Probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: Just FYI: the `PATH`-searching code won't work properly on Windows; you also have to take `PATHEXT` into account.  A mess, innit? :P